# How to display latest / updated value after successful update in MEAN stack app?

Tags: node.js, angular, mean-stack

I am trying to update a record in my MEAN stack app.

Below is some of my update code:

```
updateBusiness(person_name, business_name, business_gst_number) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {      
      this.bs.updateBusiness(person_name, business_name, business_gst_number, params['id']);
      this.router.navigate(['business']);
    });
}
```

The above code is updating the record successfully, as I can search the mongodb after executing this code.

The `this.router.navigate(['business']);` code above routes to a page that displays the record.

And here is the code run when I navigate to the `business`route:

```
 ngOnInit() {
    this.bs
      .getBusinesses()
      .subscribe((data: Business[]) => {
        this.businesses = data;
      });
}
```

Sometimes after updating, the new/updated values are displayed.

But sometimes the older values are displayed. However, when I refresh the page the updated values are displayed.

Can someone please tell me why the latest values are only being displayed sometimes after updating?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you're not really doing things in order as the update is an asynchronous operation. you're initiating the update and then navigating immediately before it finishes. to fix this, subscribe to the update in component and navigate upon completion:

```
updateBusiness(person_name, business_name, business_gst_number, id) {

    const obj = {
      person_name: person_name,
      business_name: business_name,
      business_gst_number: business_gst_number
    };

    return this //return the observable
      .http
      .post(`${this.uri}/update/${id}`, obj);
}
```

component:

```
updateBusiness(person_name, business_name, business_gst_number) {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {      
      this.bs.updateBusiness(person_name, business_name, business_gst_number, params['id'])
             .subscribe(res => this.router.navigate(['business'])); // subscribe and navigate when done
      ;
    });
}
```

this guarantees no navigation until the update is complete.